# How to prove that $\sin (x) $ is strictly increasing on $(\frac {-\pi}{2},\frac {\pi}{2}) $?

Tags: real-analysis

How prove that $\sin (x) $ is strictly increasing on $(\frac {-\pi}{2},\frac {\pi}{2}) $?

Comment: Are you allowed derivatives? If not, why not use the unit circle?

Comment: I think there is a typo, otherwise it is true vacuously :)

Comment: How do you define $\sin$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin a-\sin b=2\sin\frac{a-b}2\cos\frac{a+b}2.$$

For $a>b$, and $a,b\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, both factors are positive (first argument in the first quadrant, second argument in the first or fourth quadrant).

Answer (score 3):

we have by the first derivative $$(\sin(x))'=\cos(x)$$ and this function is positive in the gieven interval

Comment: how do i know that $\cos(x)$ is positive for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be your interval, and take $x,y\in I$ with $x<y$. Then by the mean value theorem, there exists $c$ with $x<c<y$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin{y}-\sin{x}}{y-x}&=\cos c>0\\
\frac{\sin{y}-\sin{x}}{y-x}&>0\\
\sin{y}-\sin{x}&>0\\
\sin{y}&>\sin{x}
\end{align*}
This shows that $\sin$ is an increasing function on $I$.

Comment: If derivatives are allowed, $\sin'x>0$ is simpler.