# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})\cos({\pi n})}$ is convergent, but not absolutely convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})\cos({\pi n})}$ is
>   convergent, but not absolutely convergent.

My solution:

---

Proof of convergence:

Observe that 
$\cos(n \pi) = (-1)^{n}$

so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})(-1)^{n}}$ but this is convergent*.

---

Proof of absolute convergence:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})(-1)^{n}|} > \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})} > \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$

Using fact that $\sin(x) > \frac{x}{\pi}$ for $x \in [0, \pi/2]$

### [image]

Please check my solution and I need suggestion how should proof*. Intuition tell me that it converges, because we have the alternating sign $(-1)^{n}$, so we add and subtract terms for even and odd $n$.

Comment: For * use [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: But we have $\frac{1}{n} > \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ for $n = 1$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik of course, I checked this gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** For * use [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and the fact that $\sin{x}$ [is ascending/increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110493/how-to-prove-that-sin-x-is-strictly-increasing-on-frac-pi2-frac) on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. First of all 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n} \cdot \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{\frac{\pi}{n}} \rightarrow 0$$
because $\lim\limits_{\
x\to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$.
And $$ n>m \geq2 \Rightarrow 0<\frac{\pi}{n}<\frac{\pi}{m}\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow
0<\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}<\sin{\frac{\pi}{m}}<1$$
As a result, for $a_n={\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})(-1)^{n}}$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $|a_n|$ is monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

The real fact is that $\sin(x) \leq x$ for $x\in [0, \pi/2]$. But, I think it is not hard to find an appropriate $c$ such that $\sin(x) \geq cx$ for $x\in [0, \pi/2]$. (Try to draw a graph and look at it seriously.)

Comment: I compute $c= 1/\pi$

Comment: @MartinInf1n1ty I think that works, and maybe the optimal one is $c = 2/\pi$.

Comment: @MartinInf1n1ty. Since $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\sin \pi/n}{\pi/n}=1,$ we have $\sin (\pi/n)>\frac {1}{2}(\pi/n)$ for all but finitely many $n\in \Bbb N.$